# two tables different conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to make one table output from two different selects.
first one:

```
select NAME
  from PROVIDER_GROUP 
 where ID=(select GROUP_ID 
             from CUSTOMER_GROUP
            where CUSTOMER_ID=(select CUSTOMER_ID
                                 from CUSTOMER 
                                where PHONE = 'MyNumber123'));

select PHONE 
  from CUSTOMER 
 where PHONE = "MyNumber123"
```

TABLES:

```
┌─────────────────────┐     ┌─────────────────────┐     ┌─────────────────────┐
│   PROVIDER_GROUP    │     │    CUSTOMER_GROUP   │     │       Customer      │
├─────────────────────┤     ├─────────────────────┤     ├─────────────────────┤
│        NAME         │     │      GROUP_ID       │     │     CUSTOMER_ID     │
│      GROUP_ID       │     │     CUSTOMER_ID     │     │        PHONE        │
└─────────────────────┘     └─────────────────────┘     └─────────────────────┘
```

Expected:

```
            ┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
            │       PHONE         │        NAME         │
            ├─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤   
            │    +12345678910     │ NameProviderGroup1  │
            │    +12345678910     │ NameProviderGroup2  │
            │    +12345678910     │ NameProviderGroup3  │
            └─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Comment: You should not be nesting subqueries like that: use joins instead. Also, use single quotemark for literals not double.

Comment: Your "data model" does not include SUBSCRIBER so it's hard to suggest how you might join the two queries. Is a subscriber related to a customer?

Comment: @Crcencia, How did `PROVIDER_GROUP` a table name ended up as a column name in the expected result? Are you selecting `PHONE` and `GROUP_ID`?

Comment: I need the `NAME` from `PROVIDER_GROUP`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you are asking now.  Let me know if this does the trick.

```
SELECT C.PHONE
    ,PG.NAME
FROM PROVIDER_GROUP PG
JOIN CUSTOMER_GROUP CG ON CG.GROUP_ID = PG.GROUP_ID
JOIN CUSTOMER C ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = CG.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE C.PHONE = 'MyNumber123'
```

You may need to use `LEFT JOIN` depending on whether you want to see provider groups that don't have a customer phone number attached in the `CUSTOMER_GROUP` table.

Anecdotal, but the `CUSTOMER_GROUP` table is the middle-man between your `CUSTOMER` and `PROVIDER_GROUP` table. It's a `many-to-many` relationship between those two tables. The junction table `CUSTOMER_GROUP` defines the relationships between the two.

Also, your table diagrams are very nice.

Comment: with UNION it prints the group name under phone number making one column, that's what gives me headaches

Comment: @Kimmyshor I'm confused about what your expected results are.  Is that the bottom table?  If so, is `PROVIDER_GROUP` column the `NAME` from `PROVIDER_GROUP`?

Comment: @APC If you look at the first query, it's just a very freaky-deaky way to do the joins in my answer.

Comment: I know, that's why I commented as I did on the question. My comment to you was based on your original answer. The fact that your current no longer uses UNION just proves my point;-)

Comment: @APC You are correct, my man.  I haven't been answering on here long, but I've realized sometimes you have to re-ask the question as if you were in that situation and read the metadata... because sometimes (no offense) the OP doesn't know what they are asking for.  It's like being a SQL detective!